# Append only parent UL

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is my fiddle in which I am dynamically adding LIs. The issue I am facing is that the Parent `UL` in which I am trying to add `Lis` already consist child `UL` within the `Parent LI` and on generating dynamically a new Li. The Li not only created for parent UL but also for child UL. Kindly let me know how can I change following fiddle so the (Dynamically Created) LI will only be created for `Parent <ul>`

**http://jsfiddle.net/NH5Lc/2/**

```
 $("#butadd").click(function () {
        $("ul").append("<li>Folder Name : <input type='text' class='fname' value='' required='required' /> <input type='button' class='liDelete'  value='- Remove' /> <ul class='anotherUL'><li>Dynamic Child Li</li></ul> </li>");

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already provide an id to UL, use and change your selector as

```
$("ul#folder").append("<li>Folder Name : <input type='text' class='fname' value='' required='required' /> <input type='button' class='liDelete'  value='- Remove' /> <ul class='anotherUL'><li>Dynamic Child Li</li></ul> </li>");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NH5Lc/3/)

`$("ul").append()` will target to all uls

Answer (score 2):

`$("ul").append` is targetting all the `ul`s you have to specifically select the ul you want, which is `#folder`

```
$("#folder").append("<li>Folder Name : <input type='text' class='fname' value='' required='required' /> <input type='button' class='liDelete'  value='- Remove' /> <ul class='anotherUL'><li>Dynamic Child Li</li></ul> </li>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NH5Lc/4/